# Dictionary comprehension : TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: dictionary, tags, nltk, stop-words, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   "CSV_dico.py", line 65, in 
>   = {k: [[elt.lower() for elt in v if elt.isalnum() if elt not in stopWords]for k,v in d_lemma.items]}
>   TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

This is the code - I'm trying to remove stopwords, delete punctuation from values and lowercase values in a dictionnry:

```
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

d_filtered_Words ={}                            
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('french'))
d_filtered_Words = {k: [[elt.lower() for elt in v if elt.isalnum() if elt not in stopWords]for k,v in d_lemma.items]}

print(d_filtered_Words)
```

Input

```
 {'4721': ['me', 'piquer', 'au', 'bureau', ',', 'cela', 'être', 'à', 'envisager', '(', 'avec', 'le', 'DMI1', ')', '.', 'ce', 'être', 'pas', 'quelque', 'chose', 'que', 'je', 'faire', 'car', 'je', 'ne', 'me', 'piquer', 'pas', 'dans', 'le', 'journée', 'mais', 'je', 'penser', 'que', 'ce', 'être', 'quelque', 'chose', 'qui', 'pouvoir', 'très', 'bien', 'se', 'transporter', 'dans', 'un', 'trousse', 'au', 'toilette', 'comme', 'un', 'femme', 'mettre', 'tout', 'son', 'nécessaire', 'hygiénique', 'dans', 'un', 'trousse', 'quand', 'elle', 'se', 'rendre', 'au', 'toilette', '.', 'ce', 'être', 'sympa', ',', 'ce', 'être', 'discret', '.'], '4722': ['"', 'ce', 'être', 'le', 'côté', 'discrétion', '.', 'autant', 'je', 'parler', 'très', 'facilement', 'de', 'mon', 'maladie', 'mais', 'le', 'côté', '"', '"', '"', '"', 'je', 'me', 'soigner', '"', '"', '"', '"', ',', 'je', 'aimer', 'bien', 'que', 'cela', 'rester', 'discret', '.', 'ce', 'être', 'pour', 'cela', 'que', 'je', 'aimer', 'bien', '.', '"'], '4723': ['mon', 'fille', ',', 'quand', 'elle', 'revenir', 'à', 'le', 'maison', 'ne', 'vouloir', 'pas', 'que', 'le', 'gens', 'autour', 'savoir', 'qu’elle', 'être', 'mal', 'en', 'point', '.', 'elle', 'ne', 'vouloir', 'pas', 'd’infirmier', '(', 'e', ')', 'pour', 'faire', 'son', 'piqûre', ',', 'que', 'le', 'gens', 'ne', 'savoir', 'pas', '.', 'elle', 'me', 'demander', 'de', 'lui', 'faire', 'le', 'piqûre', 'mais', 'je', 'n’aime', 'pas', 'voir', 'ce', 'aiguille', '.', 'avec', 'cela', ',', 'c’est', 'parfait', ',', 'je', 'n’ai', 'pas', 'l’impression', 'de', 'lui', 'faire', 'le', 'piqûre', '.', 'je', 'n’ai', 'même', 'pas', 'à', 'pincer', 'le', 'peau', ',', 'je', 'poser', 'sur', 'le', 'ventre', 'et', 'cela', 'se', 'faire', 'tout', 'seul', '.'], '5433': ['moins', 'cher', '...', '@card@', '%', 'de', 'moins', '...', "C'", 'être', 'quand', 'même', 'moins', 'qualitatif', 'que', 'un', 'seau', '!']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues here.

First, the error you get:

```
>>> d = {'a':'1'}
>>> d.items
<built-in method items of dict object at ...>
```

Note that `d.items` (without parentheses) is a function, and a function is not iterable:

```
>>> list(d.items)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

But `d.items()` (with parentheses) is an `dict_items` object:

```
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('a', '1')])
```

Which is iterable (that means you can call `iter` on it):

```
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', '1')]
```

Second, your dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [[elt.lower() for elt in v if elt.isalnum() if elt not in stopWords]for k,v in d_lemma.items()]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

Where would the `k` come from? It's a key from `d_lemma.items()` (note the square brackets positions):

```
>>> {k: [... for k,v in d_lemma.items()]}
```

is incorrent because `k` does not live out of the list comprehension, whereas:

```
>>> {k: [...] for k,v in d_lemma.items()}
```

is correct.

Third, the double `if` can be a `if ... and ...`

```
>>> {k: [elt.lower() for elt in v if elt.isalnum() and elt not in stopWords] for k,v in d_lemma.items()}
{'4721': ['piquer', 'bureau', 'cela', 'être', 'envisager', 'dmi1', 'être', 'quelque', 'chose', 'faire', 'car', 'piquer', 'journée', 'penser', 'être', 'quelque', 'chose', 'pouvoir', 'très', 'bien', 'transporter', 'trousse', 'toilette', 'comme', 'femme', 'mettre', 'tout', 'nécessaire', 'hygiénique', 'trousse', 'quand', 'rendre', 'toilette', 'être', 'sympa', 'être', 'discret'], '4722': ['être', 'côté', 'discrétion', 'autant', 'parler', 'très', 'facilement', 'maladie', 'côté', 'soigner', 'aimer', 'bien', 'cela', 'rester', 'discret', 'être', 'cela', 'aimer', 'bien'], '4723': ['fille', 'quand', 'revenir', 'maison', 'vouloir', 'gens', 'autour', 'savoir', 'être', 'mal', 'point', 'vouloir', 'e', 'faire', 'piqûre', 'gens', 'savoir', 'demander', 'faire', 'piqûre', 'voir', 'aiguille', 'cela', 'parfait', 'faire', 'piqûre', 'pincer', 'peau', 'poser', 'ventre', 'cela', 'faire', 'tout', 'seul'], '5433': ['moins', 'cher', 'moins', 'être', 'quand', 'moins', 'qualitatif', 'seau']}
```

Fourth, stick with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): `stopWords` should be `stop_words`, `d_filtered_Words` should be `d_filtered_words` (this is *really* important).